# JSX build output file name

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

When manually compiling React JSX with yarn and babel, **can you explicitly set the filename of the compiled js?** We are adding Reactjs to portions of pages of an existing business application so we are compiling the JSX manually by using `yarn build` command and adding a script reference to the compiled js file to a .aspx page as such

```
<script src="/client-app/build/static/js/main.9f5e5e77.js"></script>
```

This works, but every time we make a change to the JSX file and do `yarn build`, the filename changes to some random name such as *main.3d4yu632.js*. We then have to change the script reference to the new filename. It gets old when you are in development mode and you have to do this 20 times in an hour. Is there a setting somewhere in the package.json or in the .babelrc file where you can force/set the output filename?

Comment: Do you see a file called `webpack.config.js` or something similar within your project?

Comment: @arpl, No there isn't

Comment: No way anybody can help if you don't explain what happens when you invoke your build script. Would you mind providing your ´package.json´ file?